# isometric deformation of a plane

Tags: modifiers

can you please address my query.

I want to smoothly deform a plane such that the distance between the 2 points on the plane are preserved(Isometric deformation).

For example

1) In the 1stfigure, you can see in the flat mesh grid(undeformed) the distance between the vertices are constant (.222 blender units).
2) In the 2ndrd figure, i apply the wave modifier to deform the mesh. As you can see, the distance between the 2 vertices is not the same anymore.

I want to achieve the smooth, isometric deformation. Where the distance between the vertices remain constant after deformation.

How can i achieve this isometric deformation in blender?(using any of the available modifiers such as wave, wrap, deform, cloth etc etc).

Thanks
Demon

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify how this plane would be distorted? Twisting, skewing, scaling, waving? Perhaps edit your question and provide some more details like a more thorough description and reference images.

Comment: Hi :) , Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question with figures.

Answer (score 2):

### Final:

As far as I know your best shot would be with **Curve modifier**. It will not be perfectly even though but I don't think it's possible to preserve 1:1 edge length with any modifier.

[image: Final]

### Steps:

[image: steps]

1. Add **Curve** > **Bezier Curve**.
2. **Rotate** it 90 degrees on X axis.
3. Select **Plane** and add **Curve Modifier**.
4. Choose **BezierCurve**.
5. **Move** a **Plane** on X axis.

Comment: If it help you in any way consider accepting it and/or upvoting ;)

Comment: @demon, don't thank in the comments, consider upvoting the answer if it helped, or mark it as accepted if it solved your problem